# uwp youtube player stream mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm, youtube, uwp

**Solution at the end.**

I have a hard time finding informations about a youtubeplayer in uwp following the MVVM pattern.

- What are the differences between `<MediaElement>` and `<WebView>` in this context and what would be better/easier to use?
- How do I handle the events of the Player in my VM?
- VS2017 tells me that i can't use the MediaPlayerElement

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQZVS.png)

I tried other versions/builds of VS2017 but get the same error.

- Are there other ways to do this?

TY

Edit:

`<WebView>` seems to be pretty easy. Are there any downsides using it?

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Width="300" 
                              Height="225" Source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Rg1XmzzrTM" 
                              RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                              RelativePanel.Below="linkYT"/>
```

**Edit2:**

Thanks to Aditya Sharma I got on the right Track and found [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011837/uwp-youtube-player-in-mediaelement?rq=1)

So I ended up with the following:

View:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="ytPlayer"                                     
              AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
              Source="{Binding Test1, Mode=OneWay}"
              Width="600" 
              AutoPlay="True"
              Height="400"/>
```

VM:

```
public void doSomething()
{
   ...
   test1 = new Uri(convertLink(currentMovie.TrailerSource));
   ...
}

 private string convertLink(string link)
        {
           IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(link, false);
           VideoInfo video = videoInfos
               .First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == 720
                );
           return video.DownloadUrl;
        }
```

Where `Test1` is of Type `Uri` and `currentMovie.TrailerSource` is a `string`

For this to work I had to get the NuGet YouTubeExtractor.
Hope this Helps somebody get it done MVVM.

Comment: if you go to the properties of the project you can change the target version of your UWP application (in the "Application" tab)

Comment: @Florian Moser If I change the "min. Version" to the same as the "targeted Version" I get 1634 Errors (like missing using-Directiv or assembly reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the thing, We have 1. `WebView` and 2. `MediaElement`

Let's take up a deep dive into these:

**`WebView`**: is basically a phone in app browser. you can give it a link and it'll navigate to the webPage. You can use it for your youtube screening but there will be downsides:

1. You won't be able to use native controls like pause/play/seek locally. All the controls will be handled by the website rendered in a WebView.
2. You have no control on the UI as well. You'll see the basic embedded youtube UI in your app WebView that might just break your UI and might also just provide a pixelated view when scaled.

**`MediaElement`** on the other hand is quite convenient, it has a `source` property that takes a `Uri` datatype as well so the great thing is that you can pass in your `Uri` as the embedded link for the youtube vid, the MediaElement will handle everything for you plus, it'll give you some additional advantages like control over your UI, Play/Pause or even custom styling and autoplay/playRate options.

So In my opinion, I would say use a `MediaElement` over the `webView` as it'll provide you with more control over whats happening and also provide a native experience to the user.

You can find some more information on it here
 [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011837/uwp-youtube-player-in-mediaelement?rq=1) and in it's comments section.

Also, since you'll be using `mvvm` on windows 10, I would recommend you `x:bind` the `Source` property of the MediaElement to a `Uri` DataType property in a `oneWay` Mode in your `ViewModel`

Comment: Oh ty I got it working with <MediaElement>. But as much as I know the <MediaPlayerElement> has build in Controls, so no need for extra "play/pause" buttons? Just changing the xaml to <MediaPlayerElement> does not help. Any suggestions? Ty.

Comment: The `MediaPlayerElement` has inbuilt controls like play pause and all the controls that you see on the Groove Music app on windows 10, built in. For more information on how to use them follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/media-playback) and for a more descriptive information of MediaPlayerElement you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement). I'll edit my answer I didn't read the MediaPlayerElement, I thought you're enquring about the MediaElement.

Comment: Thank you again for your help!
Seems like with "                                        AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
"  MediaPlayer also supports inbuilt Play/Pause Buttons :/  
So I guess I am going with that.

Comment: Exactly! You can go with media element as well as media player element. They both will take uri as x:bind from the viewmodel. Abiding by the mvvm pattern. So choose your pick to be honest. Sticking to media element will help you provide backward compatibility while media player element won't.

Comment: Yeah I thought mediaplayerelement was some kind of new/better version of mediaelement. But I edited my Question and put in there what workes for me. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll have to undo the edit to my answer as well. You can upvote my answer as well if you feel so. Cheers

Comment: I did, but due to my "rank" the upvote won't change the publicly displayed score - but still counts.

Comment: Wow! Although I'll contribute to it.